# What free / open-source room planning tools are available?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, planning

I'm working on a project for a leasing company and they want to show a few floor plan layouts with pieces of furniture that people visiting their website can move around.

I found [Charlie's Room Planning Tool](http://wynchar.com/planner/index.html) which is OK but not exactly what I had in mind.

I have JPG images of the floor plans, I guess the trick would be to allow images of furniture to be placed on top of this "canvas" area and moved and rotated.

I know jQuery / jQueryUI supports the drag and drop, but I'm not sure I've ever seen a jQuery drag and rotate tool. It would be nice if a "jQuery room planning tool" already existed.

What free / open-source room planning tools are available? HTML5 and jQuery based tools would be preferable over flash tools.

Comment: Have any other solution?

Comment: What exactly is it that you don't like about that site? It appears to do what you are asking, but you would replace the simple blocks with imgs instead. The rooms would also be mapped with imgs instead of their simple layout. I think you're going to have to look at what they are doing and use it as a starting point for what you want. I doubt there is something exactly like what you want already out of the box. Where the site mentioned is simple, yours will build upon it and be more feature rich. Adding different types of coaches for drag and drop etc.

Comment: it lacks the wow factor. it's more like a proof of concept than something that is production ready. of course i could develop one but the reason i asked is because i'm assuming one already exists somewhere out there.